# Is it possible in C# to inherit a subclass from a subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance, subclass, mainclass

I’m studying OOP at the moment, and I’ve got this thesis. Because I know that inheriting a subclass from a superclass be like: `class superClass : subClass{ }` but I’m curious if this is an acceptable form: `class superClass : subClass1 : subclass2`.

In a nutshell, I want to inherit a subclass from another one. Because what if I get into a problem like there is a subclass and it is inherited from a superclass because they have common data. 
Thats fine right?

But here is the catch: What if I need another subclass, which has common data with both of the first subclass and the super or main class?

Comment: Are you studying "OOP" or "OOP in C#"? There are differences.

Comment: Not sure who picked that  question as duplicate, but it's a different case. This question is about straightforward sub-subclassing. The question linked as duplicate deals with the complex mess of trying to inherit from multiple classes.

Comment: The question you are asking deals with the concept of multiple inheritance.Basically you are asking is that class A inherits from Class B.So can class C inherit from class B.Yes Class C can inherit from class B.This is multiple inheritance.I think you got confused with "Multiple Inheritance" and "MultiLevel Inheritance".

Answer (score 5):

You've got it backward. Subclasses derive from superclasses, by definition.

```
class SubClass : Superclass
{
}
```

Or

```
class Dog: Animal
{
}
```

If you want to derive from a subclass that is derived from a superclass, you just need to derive from the subclass:

```
class SubClass : Superclass
{
}

class SubClass2 : Subclass
{
}
```

Or

```
class Dog: Animal
{
}

class Terrier: Dog
{
}
```

By declaring that a Terrier is a type of Dog, you are also declaring it is a type of Animal, and will have access to all of Animal's methods and properties.